# Numpy memmap and num_workers: Freezes and restart as executing multiple pytorch scripts

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, memmap

Mostly I work with huge file more than my workstation ram. So I uses numpy memmap file format with pytorch.
If I set `num_workers` more than 1, my workstation freezes and starts to reboot itself.

I tried to save those memmap files to each separate disks with the exactly same condition as `num_workers = 1`. But it still the same as freezing itself and starting to reboot.

Is there any solution or workaround for this situation?

Currently the maxium number of python script to execute simultaneously is two with `num_workers=1`.

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

def read_memmap(mem_file_name):
    with open(mem_file_name+'.conf', 'r') as file:
        memmap_configs = json.load(file)
        return np.memmap(mem_file_name, mode='r+', \
                        shape=tuple(memmap_configs['shape']), \
                        dtype=memmap_configs['dtype'])

x = read_mmap(file_path)
y = read_mmap(file_path)

dset = Dataset(x, y)

def my_dataloader(dset, batch_size):
    return DataLoader(
                    dataset     = dset, 
                    batch_size  = batch_size, 
                    num_workers = 1,
                    pin_memory  = True,
                    )
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. It's unclear how and where `num_workers` is used.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny sorry for the inconvenience. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: the OS might be relevant here, could you indicate ?

Comment: @GBy sorry for a late reply. os is ubuntu 20.04.